# how to create a column constant in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, constraints, constants

```
create table test(
  t_id SERIAL primary key,
  t_date CONSTANT date default CURRENT_DATE
);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "date"
LINE 3:   t_date CONSTANT date default CURRENT_DATE
                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "date"
SQL state: 42601
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this should work and what it should do?

Comment: I think the user will not back here... But we can imagine a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) with a "created" field and a database master that wants that this field have a "constant behaviour", preventing that careless programmers affects this "expected constraint".

Answer (score 2):

For a default value you can use a function,

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    t_id SERIAL primary key,
    t_date date DEFAULT now()
);
```

about `constant`, I never used,  even other SQL (!), only in a PL/SQL context ...

If you need a *"no update"* constraint, you can use a trigger. Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION correct_update() RETURNS trigger AS $$ 
    BEGIN
    NEW.t_date=OLD.t_date;
    RETURN NEW; 
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER no_date_update
  BEFORE BEFORE UPDATE ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (OLD.t_date IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.t_date)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE correct_update();
```

---

For a complete control, you need also trigg the INSERT event, (and does not need a default value anymore because insert trigger will do):

```
create table test(
    t_id SERIAL primary key,
    t_date date  -- a default will be redundant
);

CREATE FUNCTION correct_date() RETURNS trigger AS $$ 
    BEGIN
      IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
         NEW.t_date=now();         -- default value
      ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN  -- optional AND OLD.t_date != NEW.t_date
         NEW.t_date=OLD.t_date;    -- "constant" behaviour
      END IF;
      RETURN NEW;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER constant_date
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE correct_date();
```

The `OLD.t_date != NEW.t_date` comparison is optional, because not affects performance... But is a good practice to use it.  Another way is to check in the trigger, by `WHEN`, but only update triggers can use `OLD`... So, the best create-triggers for the same `correct_date()` function (with no old/new comparison) are:

```
CREATE TRIGGER constant_date_ins
  BEFORE INSERT  ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE correct_date();
CREATE TRIGGER constant_date_upd
  BEFORE UPDATE ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (OLD.t_date IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.t_date)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE correct_date();
```

---

## Contextualizing in a scenario

As commented above in the question, there are a lack of contextualization , ex. explaining "why you think this should work and what it should do".

### Scenario-1: the db-master need to block careless programmers

We can imagine a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) with a "created" field and a database-master that wants that this field have a "constant behaviour", preventing that careless programmers affects this "expected constraint".

That kind of scenario was used in the anwser.

### Scenario-2: the project decision is to alert by error

This is the suggestion @IgorRomanchenko  ...

```
 ... now here as a Wiki, you can EDIT and add new solution/example ...
```

Comment: It might be better to throw an exception instead of silent "do nothing" in `correct_update` trigger function.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko, yes, but even this decision (silent or not) is a "scenario dependent"... I EDIT adding scenarios, and open as Wiki for your edits.

Answer (score -1):

You want a `check` constraint

```
create table test(
  t_id SERIAL primary key,
  t_date date default CURRENT_DATE check(t_date = current_date)
);

insert into test(t_date) values (default);
INSERT 0 1

insert into test(t_date) values ('2014-01-01');
ERROR:  new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "test_t_date_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, 2014-01-01).
```

Or may be a `foreign key` constraint which allows multiple possible values and can be updated  without altering the table's schema

```
create table date_constraint (
    date_constraint date primary key
);
insert into date_constraint (date_constraint) values (current_date);

create table test(
  t_id SERIAL primary key,
  t_date date
    default CURRENT_DATE
    references date_constraint(date_constraint)
);

insert into test(t_date) values (default);
INSERT 0 1

insert into test(t_date) values ('2014-01-01');
ERROR:  insert or update on table "test" violates foreign key constraint "test_t_date_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (t_date)=(2014-01-01) is not present in table "date_constraint".
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html

Comment: Good clues for an elegant solution (!). The first `check(t_date = current_date)` is not a solution to the problem, but introduces the idea of  use a simple CHECK... The `date_constraint` is the big issue, preserving the simple CHECK... Hum, only a **problem**: I can update `test` with a date that was inserted by another record.

Comment: @Peter What do you mean by _with a date that was inserted by another record_?

Comment: `insert into date_constraint` today produces 2014-08-11. Tomorow 2014-08-12... So a programmer can do `update test SET t_date='2014-08-11';` (for all rows). This is the "careless programmers" problem that I use in my scenarious for this question, to "make scenarious sense" in the constant problem.

Comment: @Peter In the foreign key solution if that date (2014-08-11) was introduced into `date_constraint` then it is a valid date. The question is not clear about the goal so it is not possible to say that the foreign key is or is not adequate. Why do you think the check constraint is not a solution? Again the OP's goal was not explicited so not possible to evaluate the adequacy.

Comment: my opinion about "solution" here is: the behaviour MUST be like a constant behaviour; the "constant date" is date of row creation (the INSERT moment of that particular row). So, if somebody can UPDATE all rows (with different dates) to 2014-08-11, it **is an error**.